# I have created a form using HTML and Javascript, I want to display the specific dialogue based on numeber of selection. But alert does not work here

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

> ```
>   The idea is for the user to select the options and the best employment
>   sector would be suggested by the form based on his selection.
> ```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content=
    "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
    Survey that will will give you suggestion.
    </title>
    
    <style>
    
    /* Styling the Body element i.e. Color,
    Font, Alignment */
    body {
    background-color: #05c46b;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Styling the Form (Color, Padding, Shadow) */
    form {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    
    /* Styling form-control Class */
    .form-control {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    
    /* Styling form-control Label */
    .form-control label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    /* Styling form-control input,
    select, textarea */
    .form-control input,
    .form-control select,
    .form-control textarea {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    }
    
    /* Styling form-control Radio
    button and Checkbox */
    .form-control input[type="radio"],
    .form-control input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    }
    
    /* Styling Button */
    button {
    background-color: #05c46b;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 21px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
```

> The form is made with HTML. and for javascript operations i have added
> value=1 in the checkbox for generating the different output string.
> please view the code below to understand better.

```
    <body>
      <h1>Your job type survey suggestion quiz</h1>
    
    <!-- Create Form -->
    <form id="form">
    
    <!-- Details -->
    <div class="form-control">
    <label for="name" id="label-name">
        Name
    </label>
    
    <!-- Input Type Text -->
    <input type="text"
        id="name"
        placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
    <label for="email" id="label-email">
        Email
    </label>
    
    <!-- Input Type Email-->
    <input type="email"
        id="email"
        placeholder="Enter your email" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
    <label for="age" id="label-age">
        Age
    </label>
    
    <!-- Input Type Text -->
    <input type="text"
        id="age"
        placeholder="Enter your age" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
    <label for="role" id="label-role">
        Which option best describes you?
    </label>
    
    <!-- Dropdown options -->
    <select name="role" id="role">
        <option value="student">Student</option>
        <option value="intern">Intern</option>
        <option value="professional">
            Professional
        </option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
    <label>
        DO you like studying?
    </label>
    
    <!-- Input Type Radio Button -->
    <label for="recommed-1">
        <input type="radio"
            id="recommed-1"
            name="recommed">Yes</input>
    </label>
    <label for="recommed-2">
        <input type="radio"
            id="recommed-2"
            name="recommed">No</input>
    </label>
    <label for="recommed-3">
        <input type="radio"
            id="recommed-3"
            name="recommed">Maybe</input>
    </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
    <label>Skills that you have
        <small>(Check all that apply)</small>
    </label>
    <!-- Input Type Checkbox -->
    <label for="inp-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="inp" id="c" value=1>Coding</input></label>
    <label for="inp-2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="inp" id="d" value=2>Dancing</input></label>
    
    </div>
    
    <button onclick="checkCheckbox()">
    Submit
    </button>
    </form>
```

> ```
> Here as of now only 2 questions are in the form, I want to add more
>   questions and on based of the selection the form will suggest. In this
>  the alert or any message i`enter code here`s not shown neither there is any error.
> ```

```
    <script>  
    function checkCheckbox() {  
    var c = document.getElementById("c");  
    var d = document.getElementById("d");  
    var add=0  
    if (c.checked == true){  
    var y = document.getElementById("c").value;  
    var add=y;
    return add; 
    }   
    else if (d.checked == true){  
    var n = document.getElementById("d").value;  
    var add += n;  
    }  
    else {  
    return document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*Please mark any of checkbox";  
    }
    
    if(add==2){
    alert('You are multi-talented! become a dancer or a coder');
    }  
    else{
    alert('Become a coder');
    </script>  
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

> here on selecting dancing and coding a different output should be
> given and on selecting either dancing or either coding a different
> output string should be shown. please suggest for any modifications or
> if there is a better way to complete this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in the script section. You can use Web Developer debugging in your browser to check them out. I can see that you are new to coding in general, so there are a couple of common mistakes we've all made in the beginning.

This is one way of writing the function so it works as I think you intended it:

```
    function checkCheckbox() {  
        var c = document.getElementById("c");  
        var d = document.getElementById("d");  
        var add = 0, val;
        if (c.checked == true){  
            val = "coder";
            add += 1;
        }   
        if (d.checked == true){  
            val = "dancer";
            add += 1;
        }  

        if (add == 2) {
            alert('You are multi-talented! become a dancer or a coder');
            return true;
        }  
        else if (add == 1) {
            alert('Become a ' + val);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*Please mark any of checkbox";  
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also, you need to add `return` in the event handler of the button, to avoid it submitting when the form is invalid:

```
   <button onclick="return checkCheckbox()">Submit</button>
```

And lastly add an element for the error message that is referred to in the script. Something like:

```
   <div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: Also, instead of alert can you recommend something which would look more beautiful as the output? or is there any other alert types/fonts that you are familiar with? I was hoping to put something like a message box.

Comment: @siddxx18 It's not my area, but it's something you can do with CSS. Check [this](https://html-online.com/articles/simple-popup-box/) out.

Comment: nevermind i used Sweetalert for that. but there's a huge problem. i did the code in javascript but i am running it on xampp. so i actually had to do it in PHP. WHAT A WASTE OF TIME and I have a deadline in 2 days:/